# Pyside: Changing QPixmap image with button press

Tags: python, image, pyside, maya, qpixmap

I am making a tool in maya using pyside.  I was able to add an image to my UI using QPixmap and adding it to QLabel.  I am trying to figure out how to get the image to change with a press of a button (by pointing into to a new image path) but i am having trouble figuring out how to get it to change.

```
self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap(image_path)
self.lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel()
self.lbl.setPixmap(self.pix)
pic_layout.addWidget(self.lbl)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add button:

```
self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
```

Subscribe to clicked event:

```
self.button.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)
```

Add click handler:

```
def button_clicked(self, *args):
    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(new_image_path)
    self.lbl.setPixmap(pixmap)
```

`new_image_path` here is path to new image

Answer (score 1):

you can use the load method of the QPixmap object

```
    self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap(image_path)
    self.lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel()
    self.lbl.setPixmap(self.pix)
    
    self.button = QPushButton('Change Image')
    self.button.clicked.connect(self.changeImageHandler)
    
    
    pic_layout.addWidget(self.lbl)

def changeImageHandler(self):
    self.pix.load(new_image_path)
    self.lbl.setPixmap(self.pix)
```